# how to create dynamic Required field Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have generated an array of required field validators using following code:

```
 Panel[] divMain = new Panel[22];
 DropDownList[] gender = new DropDownList[22];
 TextBox[] txtFirstName = new TextBox[22];
 TextBox[] txtMiddleName = new TextBox[22];
 TextBox[] txtLastName = new TextBox[22];
 TextBox[] txtAge = new TextBox[22];
 RequiredFieldValidator[] req = new RequiredFieldValidator[30];
```

and i am creating some dynamic controls using following code:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < noOfad - 1; i++)
        {


            HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            HtmlGenericControl strong = new HtmlGenericControl("strong");
            strong.InnerText = "Adult" + Convert.ToString(i + 2);
            p.Controls.Add(strong);
            divAdultMoreForm.Controls.Add(p);
            Panel div = new Panel();
            HtmlGenericControl p1 = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            p1.InnerHtml = "<span><strong>Full Name (As per Valid Govt Id Proof valid )</strong></span> <span><strong style='  margin-left: 549px;'>Age(in Years 18 +) </strong></span>";
            div.Controls.Add(p1);

            HtmlGenericControl p2 = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            gender[i] = new DropDownList();
            gender[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Title", "0"));
            gender[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Mr.", "1"));
            gender[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Mrs.", "2"));
            gender[i].Items.Add(new ListItem("Ms.", "3"));
            gender[i].CssClass = "txt";
            p2.Controls.Add(gender[i]);

            txtFirstName[i] = new TextBox();
            txtFirstName[i].Attributes.Add("placeholder", "First Name");
            txtFirstName[i].CssClass = "txt input";
            txtFirstName[i].ID = "txtFirstName" + Convert.ToString(i);
            req[i].ControlToValidate = txtFirstName[i].ID;//Object refrence not set to an instance ofo an object
            req[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            req[i].ErrorMessage = "*";
            txtFirstName[i].CssClass = "input txt";
            txtMiddleName[i] = new TextBox();
            txtMiddleName[i].Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Middle Name");
            txtMiddleName[i].CssClass = "txt input";
            txtMiddleName[i].CssClass = "input txt";
            txtMiddleName[i].ID = "txtMiddleName" + Convert.ToString(i);
            txtLastName[i] = new TextBox();
            txtLastName[i].Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Last Name");
            txtLastName[i].CssClass = "txt input";
            txtLastName[i].CssClass = "input txt";
            txtLastName[i].ID = "txtLastName" + Convert.ToString(i);
            txtAge[i] = new TextBox();
            txtAge[i].Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Age");
            txtAge[i].CssClass = "txt";
            p2.Controls.Add(txtFirstName[i]);

            p2.Controls.Add(txtMiddleName[i]);

            p2.Controls.Add(txtLastName[i]);

            p2.Controls.Add(txtAge[i]);

            div.Controls.Add(p2);
            divAdultMoreForm.Controls.Add(div);
        }
```

But when i am assigning the control to validate to the validator req[i] then there comes an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Can not understand why this problem is occuring.
Any help to correct my code!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you forgot to initialize the `RequiredFieldValidator` array object. This seems to be missing from your code :

```
req[i] = new RequiredFieldValidator();
```

After this you can play with its properties.

Hope this clears it.

Comment: how can i set the display property of req1 to none dynamically

Comment: Use this : `req[i].Display = ValidatorDisplay.None;`

Comment: Thanks! But The Method u suggested is working file with None But When i am using it with ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic; its Not working. may be because i am unable to set the innerText of req1[i]. i want to set the 'req1[i].InnerText= " * " ;'

Comment: There is no `InnerText` property for requiredFieldValidator. I hope you are not confused between ErrorMessage and InnerText. The InnerText is available for the HTML manipulation, not here for RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: i am using RFV with DropDownList but its not working any problem with my code?  `req5[i] = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                req5[i].ControlToValidate = gender[i].ID;
                req5[i].InitialValue ="Title";
                req5[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                req5[i].ErrorMessage = "Please Select Title for Adult" + Convert.ToString(i + 2);
                req5[i].Display = ValidatorDisplay.None; `

Comment: Funny how you remove the answer everytime. :) Kid. Anyway, the answer in your case is that you have to specify the `InitialValue` attribute to your dropdown like this : `req5[i].InitialValue="0";` or `req5[i].InitialValue="Your First Entry";` whichever works for you.